# Failed to start Bluetooth Service

Tags: bluetooth, pi-4

Could someone help me to rectify this error?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-01-21 05:47:23 GMT; 42s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
  Process: 932 ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --nonplugin=sap (code=exi
 Main PID: 932 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 21 05:47:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jan 21 05:47:23 raspberrypi bluetoothd[932]: Unknown option --nonplugin=sap
Jan 21 05:47:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Main process exited, 
Jan 21 05:47:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Failed with result 'e
Jan 21 05:47:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Bluetooth service.
```

Comment: There's a bit of a clue `Unknown option --nonplugin=sap`. Where is that option set?